# how to Use Filter operator in foreach in pig latin

Tags: hadoop, foreach, filter, apache-pig

I am trying to use `FILTER` operator within foreach to filter some of my data, but it is throwing an error. I am using the below query:

```
ctm_pm_v1_stg = LOAD '/datalake/uhc/ei/pi_ara/hive/warehouse/ctm_pm.db/ctm_pm_t1' USING PigStorage ('\u0001') AS (lob:chararray,day_phnno:chararray,eve_phnno:chararray,mbr_name:chararray,hic_no:chararray,contract_no:chararray,ctm_risk_category:chararray);
ctm_pm_v1 = FOREACH ctm_pm_v1_stg {
fdata = FILTER ctm_pm_v1_stg by ctm_risk_category=='High';
GENERATE ctm_risk_category;
};
```

if anyone have some idea on this please help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

`Nested FOREACH` will work only with bags but your `relation(ctm_pm_v1_stg)` doesn't have any bags. To fix this issue just remove the nested part and use only `FILTER stmt`.

```
ctm_pm_v1_stg = LOAD '/datalake/uhc/ei/pi_ara/hive/warehouse/ctm_pm.db/ctm_pm_t1' USING PigStorage ('\u0001') AS (lob:chararray,day_phnno:chararray,eve_phnno:chararray,mbr_name:chararray,hic_no:chararray,contract_no:chararray,ctm_risk_category:chararray);
fdata = FILTER ctm_pm_v1_stg by (ctm_risk_category=='High');
DUMP fdata;
```